# Magento 1.9 - Cannot View Dataflow Advanced Profiles Page in Admin

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9

I am trying to create new advanced profile in Magento 1.9, but I can't seem to get to the list page (System > Import/Export > Dataflow - Advanced Profiles).

Here is the stack trace for the list page:

```
ERR (3): 
exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message 'Invalid block type: Mage_Adminhtml_Block_System_Convert_Profile_Grid' in /home/test/public_html/mg1/app/Mage.php:595

Stack trace:
#0 
/home/test/public_html/mg1/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(495): Mage::throwException('Invalid block t...')

#1 
/home/test/public_html/mg1/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(437): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_getBlockInstance('adminhtml/syste...', Array)

#2 
/home/test/public_html/mg1/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Grid/Container.php(66): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->createBlock('adminhtml/syste...', 'system_convert_...')

#3 
/home/test/public_html/mg1/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(293): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Container->_prepareLayout()

#4 
/home/test/public_html/mg1/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(456): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->setLayout(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout))

#5
/home/test/public_html/mg1/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/System/Convert/ProfileController.php(84): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->createBlock('adminhtml/syste...', 'convert_profile')

#6
/home/test/public_html/mg1/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Adminhtml_System_Convert_ProfileController->indexAction()

#7 
/home/test/public_html/mg1/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(254): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')

#8 
/home/test/public_html/mg1/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))

#9 
/home/test/public_html/mg1/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(365): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()

#10 
/home/test/public_html/mg1/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)

#11 
/home/test/public_html/mg1/index.php(83): Mage::run('', 'store')

#12 
{main}
```

Any ideas on what to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to a new security feature Magento introduced with its version 1.9.

As the error message showd you need to whitelist the block `adminhtml/system_convert_profile_grid`.

To do that you can go to `System > Permissions > Blocks` and enter the block above.